# Ubnutu on Virtualbox shows error: not a directory

Tags: boot, grub2, virtualbox, kubuntu

I have Ubuntu 18.04 in a Virtualbox hosted on a Windows 10 system. It has suddenly blocked and after restarting it can not boot Ubuntu and shows the following error:

`error: not a directory. Press any key to continue...`

Most of the advanced options also result in the same error loop.
I got access to the grub. The ls command there also results in the same error.

`ls (hd0<tab>` however, results in a bit more information as
`No known filesystem detected - Sector size 5128 - Total size 15726592KiB Partition hd0,msdos1: No known filesystem detected - Partition start at 1024KiB - Total size 15726592KiB`

I wanted to do something similar to [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/repair-linux-boot-with-grub-rescue/). I attached [the results of a set command followed by ls command in grub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YbRE.png). Since the ls does not recognize any device, I don't know how to continue.

Might be relevant to know that the day before, I downloaded new ubuntu updates but did not restart the system before this incident.

Can someone please help me realize what went wrong there? and ideally how to fix it?